# as 2 to as3 conversion

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How to translate this as2 code to as3?

```
topHome_mc.onRollOver = function  () {
topHome_mc.gotoAndPlay("over");
}

topHome_mc.onRollOut = function  () {
    topHome_mc.gotoAndPlay("out");
}

topHome_mc.onRelease = function() {
    mcLoader.loadClip("home.swf",myLoader);
    stick("gh_mc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add the listeners to the object
topHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,onMouseOverHandler);
topHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,onMouseOutHandler);
topHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onMouseClickHandler);

//handle rollover
function onMouseOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
//handle roll out
function onMouseOutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.gotoAndPlay("out");
}
//handle click
function onMouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.load(new URLRequest('home.swf'));
    //assume myLoader is already created
    myLoader.addChild(loader);
    stick("gh_mc");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// add our mouse listeners
topHome_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, this._onOver );
topHome_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this._onOut );
topHome_mc.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, this._onClick );

// called when we mouse over it
private function _onOver( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    topHome_mc.gotoAndPlay( "over" );
}

// called when we mouse out of it
private function _onOut( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    topHome_mc.gotoAndPlay( "out" );
}

// called when we click on it
private function _onClick( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    // create a loader to load the swf
    var l:Loader = new Loader();
    l.load( new URLRequest( "home.swf" ) );
    myLoader.addChild( l );

    // do whatever this does
    stick( "gh_mc" );
}
```

For the Loader object, you should probably be adding event listeners for the different status events: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary